# Object of class EE_Session could not be converted to string in DevDemons forms

Tags: php, forms, bug, devdemon

I've installed the latest version of DevDemons Forms(3.3.5)

When I navigate to the index page of the Control Panel I'll get the following error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message:  Object of class EE_Session could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: forms/ext.forms.php
>
> Line Number: 240

I also found a bug report on the Ellislab website related to this problem https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19469

Answer (score 1):

This is something that DevDemon will need to look into as it relates to the Session class constructor where the session_start hook is being called which corrupts the last call object. Instead of a string it is now returning an object which throws the error. The fix will most likely require a change to grab the last_call content before loading the session library and append this when returning a value in the cp_js_end hook.

Answer (score 0):

For bug reports could you please open up a support request at our site? That is the fastest way to get bug reports fixed/processes.

Comment: I did, but normally when I open a support request it will take a while(IMO stackexchange is a faster way to solve the problem or get a workaround).